# unable to get react context value in js function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a context function and add some data in the context in tsx file

```
 const orderContext = useContext(OrderContext);
    orderDetail.userEmail = email;
    orderDetail.userName = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
```

When i try to get the values in order.js file [not tsx file]

```
const orderContext = useContext(OrderContext);
console.log(orderContext.orderDetail.userEmail)
```

it is showing empty value but when i try to get same value from `orderContext.orderDetail.userEmail` in tsx file i can see the value stored.

Comment: you need to add the state and the function to define the state, in your provider's value, and inside your child component of the provider you have the function to define the state, and the values ​​that come from the useContext

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code here:

```
// context.tsx
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

export const Context = createContext({
  order: { userEmail: '' },
  setOrder: () => {
    //
  },
});

export const OrderProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState({ userEmail: '' });
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ order, setOrder }}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};

// your page.tsx
export const Home = () => {
  const { order, setOrder } = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{order.userEmail}</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setOrder({ userEmail: e.currentTarget.value })}
        value={order.userEmail}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

// routes.tsx
<OrderProvider>
  <Home />
</OrderProvider>
```